An integral bound for two quadratic polynomials
Let us consider two  quadratic polynomials depending
on two parameters
$$F(x) = 1 + 2 p x +  p q x^{2},$$
$$G(x) = 1 + 2 q x +  p q x^{2},$$
where $x > 0$. Here $p > 0$, $q > 0$ are parameters.
It is necessary to prove the following integral bound
$$\int_{0}^{+ \infty} d x [p (F(x))^{- 2} G(x) 
    - q(G(x))^{- 2} F(x)] \leq 0$$
for all $0 < p \leq q$.
For  $p = q > 0$ we get $F(x) = G(x)$ and integral vanishes.
The numerical calculations for certain $p$ and $q$ give also a support for this bound.

Welcome to MSE. I suggest you consider the function $f(t) = \int_0^t pF(x)^{-2}G(x) -  qG(x)^{-2}F(x) \mathrm{d}x $. You should be able to evaluate this using the fundamental theorem of calculus and partial fraction decomposition. Then consider $\lim_{t\to\infty} f(t)$.

Thank you! The limit does exist. I will not surprise if it will be zero.

Note that
$$p\frac{G(x)}{F^2(x)}-q\frac{F(x)}{G^2(x)}=\frac{G^2(x)}{F^2(x)}\frac{pF(x)-qG(x)}{F(x)G(x)}=\frac{G(x)}{F^3(x)}(pF(x)-qG(x)).$$
But
$$pF(x)-qG(x)=(p-q)+2(p^2-q^2)x+pq(p-q)x^2=(p-q)R(x),$$
where
$$R(x)=1+2(p+q)x+pqx^2$$
Since $F(x), G(x), R(x)$ are positive on $[0,\infty)$ and $p<q$ we obtain
$$\int_0^t\left(p\frac{G(x)}{F^2(x)}-q\frac{F(x)}{G^2(x)}\right)dx=(p-q)\int_0^t\frac{G(x)R(x)}{F^3(x)}dx<0$$
for all $t>0$.

Thanks a lot for the answer!

@Vladimir You are Welcome!
